# htaccess redirect everything to example.com/index.htm

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect any request from one domain to another but not request the page on the new domain or pass parameters. The closest I got was:

RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com

but this passes the parameters (e.g. ?param=one) which is messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
... when you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution 
string with just a question mark.
```

So, I guess this should work:

```
   RedirectMatch permanent ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/?
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much it - still shows the question mark though.